# Best way to include AND exclude?

Tags: mysql

I have a large table that contains product IDs and product category IDs.

I want to select product IDs that are in a certain list of category IDs, AND exclude the product ID entirely if it's in another list of category IDs.

Example table:

```
prod_id cat_id
------- ------
1       10
1       11
2       10
2       11
2       12
3       10
3       11
```

So I want to see all products that have category IDs 10 and 11, BUT if they are also have category ID 12, they must be excluded.

I was thinking this would work, but it does not:

```
SELECT prod_id from products WHERE cat_id IN (10,11) AND NOT IN (12)
```

This seems like it should be really easy and common, but I'm just not getting it.

Comment: If a product has only category 10 (or only 11), should it be in the result?

Comment: yes, and my understanding of "IN" is that a match of any of those members is a match.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [NOT EXISTS](https://explainextended.com/2009/09/18/not-in-vs-not-exists-vs-left-join-is-null-mysql/) for this purpose.

```
SELECT DISCTINCT
    prod_id
FROM
    products p1
WHERE
    cat_id IN (10, 11)
    AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                    FROM   products p2
                    WHERE  p1.prod_id = p2.prod_id
                           AND cat_id = 12);
```

Comment: this is perfect, thanks.  I need to sit with this a bit to digest why it works. :)

Answer (score 1):

> I want to see all products that have category IDs 10 and 11

If this mean "at least one record with ID 10 or 11":

```
SELECT prod_id 
FROM products 
GROUP BY prod_id 
HAVING SUM(cat_id IN (10,11)) > 0 
   AND SUM(cat_id = 12) = 0
```

If this mean "at least one record with ID 10 and at least one record with ID 11":

```
SELECT prod_id 
FROM products 
GROUP BY prod_id 
HAVING SUM(cat_id = 10) > 0 
   AND SUM(cat_id = 11) > 0 
   AND SUM(cat_id = 12) = 0
```